# Angular style background image url + linear gradient

Tags: css, angular

I want to put a picture in a div, while using a gradient. After some tries, my best solution is this one:

```
<div 
  class="form-edit-picture-wrapper"
  [style.background-image]="'linear-gradient(-225deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 50%, rgba(0,36,61,0.6) 80%), url(/assets/hands.jpeg)'"
>
```

But still not working.

Any help?

Comment: try `[ngStyle]="{'background-image': '...'}"`

Answer (score 2):

Use plain css and not inline styles!

```
.form-edit-picture-wrapper{
    background: linear-gradient(-225deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 50%, rgba(0,36,61,0.6) 80%),
    url(/assets/hands.jpeg)
}
```

You would also need to set height and width as there seems to be no content in the div you provided.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use it in the template you can use the `[ngStyle]` directive.

```
[ngStyle]="{background: 'linear-gradient(-225deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 50%, rgba(0,36,61,0.6) 80%), url(/assets/hands.jpeg)'}"
```

Here's a quick [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ysca8d)

Answer (score 1):

using @Nikhil Chandu answer, but using pipe.

make class pipe :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { DomSanitizer, SafeStyle } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
    name: 'sanitizeStyle'
})
export class SanitizeStylePipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private _sanitizer:DomSanitizer) {
    }

    transform(v:string):SafeStyle {
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(v);
    }
}
```

using **sanitizeStyle**

```
<div  [style.background-image]="'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)), url(../assets/image.png)' | sanitizeStyle">
```

Answer (score 0):

sanitize and it shall work:

in your .ts file:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

in your export class add:

```
bgImage:any;
```

in your constructor add:

```
private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
```

then create an image url and sanitize:

```
this.bgImage = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle('linear-gradient(-225deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 50%, rgba(0,36,61,0.6) 80%),url(/assets/hands.jpeg)');
```

Thats the sanitizing part.

Now in your html:

```
<div [style.background-image]="bgImage">
```

There is also an other way to do this without sanitizing using ngStyle:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'linear-gradient(-225deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 50%, rgba(0,36,61,0.6) 80%),url(/assets/hands.jpeg)'}"></div>
```

hope that helps!

Answer (score -2):

you can do it like this:

```
<div class="image">
 <image src="url" alt="">
</div>
```

.css file:

```
.image {
  background: linear-gradient(-225deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 50%, rgba(0,36,61,0.6) 80%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-225deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 50%, rgba(0,36,61,0.6) 80%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-225deg, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 50%, rgba(0,36,61,0.6) 80%);
}
```

Comment: The point here is not to put an **actual** image in the div but to have *two* background images...which is entirely possible. I think you have misunderstood the question